# ¿Como se abre una imagen o archivo que se encuentra en otra carpeta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy aprendiendo Python en mi primer año de universidad y quiero trabajar en una visual novel, pero sin utilizar ningún motor gráfico.

Estoy haciendo uso de Tkinter en la versión de Python 3.6 y para poder mantener cierto orden en todos los archivos que usaré, quiero saber si es posible poder guardar las imágenes y los distintos archivos .py que usaré en el desarrollo, en una carpeta y abrirlas desde ahí.

Este es mi código:

---

```
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()

imagen = PhotoImage(file = 'NicoMostacho.ppm')

canvas = Canvas(ventana)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_image(150, 130, image = imagen)


ventana.mainloop()
```

---

Por ejemplo en este código la imagen se muestra sin problemas, pero me gustaría guardarla en una subcarpeta, pero me genera el siguiente error:

> tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "NicMostacho.ppm": no such file or directory

Comment: Hola Fritaku, la pregunta es muy genérica. La respuesta es si. Puedes guardar las imágenes y demás recursos donde quieras, simplemente debes usar la ruta absoluta o relativa adecuada al abrirlos. En el caso de los módulos que van a ser importados ya depende de la estructura del proyecto, de si vas a crear un paquete o no, etc pero por supuesto que se puede (y es lo normal) estructurar un proyecto en distintos subdirectorios. Agrega algo de más información o el error concreto que tienes (junto a un [mcve]) para poder orientarte mejor. Un Saludo.

Comment: Gracias por responder, acabo de hacer una edición a la pregunta.  Espero que así esté más clara

Comment: Según error el nombre de tu fichero es `NicMostacho.ppm`  y en tu código es `NicoMostacho.ppm`. Vigila que el nombre no sea como parece incorrecto. Por otro lado, si tu carpeta con la imágen es un subdirectorio localizado en el mismo nivel que tu main.py simplemente basta con usar la ruta relativa a él,  por ejemplo si tu carpeta se llamara `imagenes` debería ser `imagen = PhotoImage(file = 'imagenes/NicoMostacho.ppm')` Para dar una respuesta exacta debes mostrar la estructura de los archivos y directorios de tu proyecto.

Comment: Bueno, solo me queda decir que te amo, jajkajaj era justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias